# Merge only lines that they are touches on QGIS 3.2.3 and create a shapefile output with the result

Tags: shapefile, line, merge, qgis-3

I have a project with five lines, every element have a different ID. This is view below:

[image]

I want to merge only lines that there are touching. According with this conditions the lines they should become two. After this i want to export all into shapefile format. The result is view here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the following steps:

- Add a new field name NewID of integer type
- Give the IDs 1,2 and 3 a common NewID of 1
- Give the IDs 4 and 5 a common NewID of 2
- Use Line dissolve tool from `Saga -> Vector line tools -> Line dissolve` and choose the NewID field that you created in the first step to merge all the above lines with their common IDs

Comment: Ok ahmadhanb, this is being useful in the future. What i showed on the top is only a example. In truth the results must be  merged 1, merged 2, merged 3... until 125. It's too much expensive that method.

Answer (score 0):

`Dissolve` all the lines. This combines them all into one multipart feature.

Use `multiparts to single parts` to the multipart feature into single part features.

Comment: Not csk is wrong. The way of ahmadhanb right

Comment: Please **accept the correct answer by clicking the check mark** next to it so no one else wastes their time trying to answer a question which apparently has been already answered correctly.

Comment: Csk when you answered i checked immediatly the correct answer. What ahmadhand wrote is a possible way but i'm sure that isn't fast method. If there are no alternatives anyway.